# How to execute multiple command on file open?

Tags: vimrc, performance

Syntax highlighting slowing my vim down.
I set

```
syntax sync maxlines=100
syntax sync minlines=100
```

Now i need to execute

```
:syntax off
:syntax on
```

After every new file getting opened to save performance. How can i do it? May there is better solution?

Comment: I'd say it's unlikely that syntax highlighting is slowing you down. Try to disable you plugins or maybe you can describe your issue better.

Comment: @laktak I tried to switch syntax off and vim started working faster. Then if I switch syntax back it slows down again (but if file isn't large it works well). Terrible lags appear if I edit html

Answer (score 2):

My vim was slowing down because of `Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'`. @laktak you was right